# Pentaho replace table name in a loop dynamically

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi, spoon

I currently have a transformation setup with 2 table inputs and one Merge Rows (Diff), the SQL select statement in both table inputs are constant, they are not changing except for the table name. So I have:

```
select * from THIS_WILL_CHANGE
```

I have around 100 tables and I don't want to manually enter the table names every iteration, especially because this is automation...

What is the best way to achieve this? Is there any way to read like a CSV file with all the table names and loop that way? Any help is appreciated..

Comment: do all the 100 tables have same columns or different columns in it?

Comment: They all have the same columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something I've had to do before too!
You can do this with a variable and a job which executes once for each row of the previous step.

1. Create a parent job to host these steps
2. Create a transformation which gets the table names from 'somewhere' eg. CSV file, or database query - a select on all_tables for tables with the same column names might be a nice way to do this for all time...
3. In this same transformation, use copy rows to result step to push the data back to the job
4. Create a new 'sub job', which executes once for each row, and has a hop from the 'get data' step in the main job
5. In the sub job, create two transformations, one to set the variable from the results field, and one to do your select
6. In your select query, check the box 'substitute variables' and place your variable with the same name as your set variables step into your SQL as ${yourVariableHere}

I've put this in an image below, which hopefully helps you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic sql row step is a good option for this, provided the tables all have the same layout/metadata.